# Linking directly to Contact's Activity from Scheduled Reminder Email

Tags: wordpress, activities, scheduled-reminders

I've created a Scheduled Reminder email that triggers 1 hour before each SCHEDULED Meeting or Phone Activity.

In the reminder email I want to include a link directly to the "With Contact" for the Activity. Or, even better, link to the Activity so that I can easily update the Activity.

What's the URL/Token combination needed for a direct link to the Contact's Activity?

This doesn't appear to be covered in the documentation: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens

I'm using Wordpress as my CMS.
[image: Scheduled Reminder Settings]

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION FOUND
It wasn't rocket science but I'm putting it here in case others need it (or when I forget).

Here's how to create a link that will take you directly to an Activity in CiviCRM.

EDIT ACTIVITY PAGE ON WORDPRESS CMS

http://www.MyOrganization.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contact/view/activity&atype=2&action=UPDATE&reset=1&id={activity.activity_id}&cid={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}&context=activity

VIEW ACTIVITY

http://www.MyOrganization.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contact/view/activity&atype=2&action=VIEW&reset=1&id={activity.activity_id}&cid={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}&context=activity

If you're using a different CMS you can find the root URL structures at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens